# AddEventListener event fires only once

Tags: javascript, django

I am using Django templating engine and JavaScript. My HTML looks like this

```html
<p class="content-card__address">{{ z.formatted_address|truncatewords:6 }}</p>
<div class="content-card-inner">
  <p class="content-card__review">Отзывы ({{ z.post_relate.all.count }})</p>
  <p class="content-card__phone">{{ z.international_phone_number }}</p>
  <div class="div-shaddow"></div>
  <p class="content-card__text">Показать</p>
</div>
```

Cards with text to be generated on the backend using a template engine. My JavaScript code only works on the first card and I need it to work on all cards. With JavaScript I add a class to the div elements. Here is my JavaScript

```js
let call = document.querySelector('.content-card__text');
let divShadow = document.querySelector('.div-shaddow');
call.addEventListener('click', clickCall)

function clickCall() {
  call.classList.add('visually-hidden');
  divShadow.classList.add('visually-hidden');
}
```

Comment: What is `call`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code returns you the first element in the DOM and you add click handlers only for it

```
document.querySelector('.content-card__text')
```

It will work for you:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.content-card__text');

buttons.forEach(button => {
   button.addEventListener('click', clickCall);
});
```

But please also note that you need to take this into account when working with `.divShadow` if this element is not alone on the page

Update: example based on your comment

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.content-card__text');
const divShadow = document.querySelectorAll('.div-shaddow');

buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
   button.addEventListener('click', () => clickCall(index));
});

function clickCall(index) {
  buttons[index].classList.add('visually-hidden');
  divShadow[index].classList.add('visually-hidden');
}
```

Comment: I get an error when using.Cannot read property 'add' of undefined.

Comment: Please note that now in `buttons` (or `call`) you have an array of elements, and not one element, so you need to change the clickCall function itself